# BEFSR41 to wireless?

Tags: router, wireless-router, broadband

I have the following device: BEFSR41

What is the best way to add wireless capabilities to this?  Can I buy a wireless switch, attach the switch to one of the ports on the BEFSR41, and have wireless in the house?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a "wireless access point" (not wireless switch), which would get its own IP on the network, and plug in directly to one of the ports on your router's switch, and you would have wireless.

That said, a WAP costs roughly the same as a new router with wireless built in.

Comment: I agree - adding a WAP would be more expensive.  A WAP/Router can often be found for less than a WAP by itself.  That and upgrading to a new device, most support Gigabit Ethernet, maybe USB NAS (semi - NAS? - not a real NAS), and other nice things that only adding a WAP won't give you.  Plus you don't increase the number of AC bricks and devices.

Comment: @Blackbeagle I was also thinking that his router has a 4-port switch, and by adding a WAP, he loses a port he may need later.

Comment: Is a new router with wireless which also have wired capabilities cheaper than adding wap to the old router?

Comment: @oshirowanen Of course it depends on what you buy, some WAP's could even be more. Assuming the same general quality, it is probably within $10, and as I said, you would not lose a port on your switch to the WAP. It is also easier than managing two devices, more potential for one of two to fail, and it uses more power. In other words, there are a lot of good reasons to just replace the router with a wireless one, UNLESS you find a WAP that is a really good deal.